# Which join command should I use if I want only the values in the table2 that are not present in table1

Tags: sql, join, select

Joins always gets me :/
so far what I have is

```
SELECT  *
FROM    
    #Table1 aa
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    #Table2 bb
ON  a.FieldA = b.FieldB
```

Comment: Please read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with a more complete example. In the meantime, `SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON b.FieldB = a.FieldA WHERE a.OtherField IS NULL` should get you close.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommmend `not exists`:

```
select t2.*
from #table2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from #table1 t1 where t1.fieldA = t2.fieldB)
```

This seems like the most straight-forward way to express what you want, and should have good performance, provided that you have indexes on `#table2(fieldB)` and `#table1(fieldA)`.

If you really want to do this with a `join`, then you can use an anti-`left join,` like so:

```
select t2.*
from #table2 t2
left join #table1 t1 on t1.fieldA = t2.fieldB
and t1.fieldA is null
```

The logic is to attempt to join both tables, and pull out records of `#table2` for which the join did not succeed.